# php cookies block access to directories

Tags: php, mysql, directory, blocking

I have a mysql database of users that can login to my site and view content. I would like to block a couple of directories from certain users. What is the best way to do this.

Currently when a user logs in a cookie is created with their customer id and the customer is is used to display their content.

How would I block entire directories from my users???

EDIT: I need to allow one user in my database to access the directories once logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:

**[Mod_rewrite - Deny access to certain folders](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=650756)**

More Info:

http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-tips-and-tricks.html

Comment: @user: You can use mysql's `GRANT`, more info here: http://www.ntchosting.com/mysql/grant.html